# How can I solve my easy system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

I am new to *Mathematica* and am afraid this is a silly question. I have this very easy substitution, it has three equations on three unknowns `{w1, l1, t1}`. I want to substitute the first two equations into the the third one, so that everything is in terms of w1 ***and then solve for w1***. In pen and paper this is simple. I have tried many ways to do this with mathematica but Solve just stalls. Any suggestions as to how I could isolate w1?

**Equations**

```
l1w1optlag = Flatten[Solve[MRSw1andl1 == 0, l1]]
```

> ```
> {l1 -> (pw^2 w1)/((1 + a e1)^2 w^2)}
> ```

```
t1w1optlag = Flatten[Solve[MRSw1andt1 == 0, t1]]
```

> ```
> {t1 -> (pw^2 w1)/((1 + a e1)^2 r^2)}
> ```

```
focwrtlam == 0
```

> ```
> 1 - (Sqrt[l1]/d + Sqrt[t1]/d + Sqrt[w1]/d)^2 == 0
> ```

All I want to do is plug the first two equations on the the third one and solve for w1. Notice that I am getting rules for the first two equations. I have tried converting these rules to equations or evaluating the third expression with these rules and solving it as follows but it doesn't work:

```
Solve[focwrtlam == 0 /.t1w1optlag /.l1w1optlag,w1]
```

Comment: `(1 - (Sqrt[l1]/d + Sqrt[t1]/d + Sqrt[w1]/d)^2 == 
   0) /. {l1 -> (pw^2 w1)/((1 + a e1)^2 w^2), 
  t1 -> (pw^2 w1)/((1 + a e1)^2 r^2)}`

Comment: If I ask Mathematica to isolate w1 it cant handle the job it stalls. How can I isolate w1 after evaluating the third expression with the other two?

Comment: Solve first two for `{l1, t1}` and plug solution(s) into third.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is easier to handle if it put into an equivalent form.

```
eq1 = Sqrt[l1] + Sqrt[t1] + Sqrt[w1] == d;
```

It is also to convenient to write the rules as

```
r1 = {l1 -> (pw^2 w1)/((1 + a e1)^2 w^2)};
r2 = {t1 -> (pw^2 w1)/((1 + a e1)^2 r^2)};
```

and substitute `u^2` for `w1` getting a new equation

```
eq2 = eq1 /. Join[r1, r2] /. w1 -> u^2
```

> ```
> Sqrt[u^2] + Sqrt[(pw^2 u^2)/((1 + a e1)^2 r^2)] + 
>   Sqrt[(pw^2 u^2)/((1 + a e1)^2 w^2)] == d
> ```

This can be simplified

```
 eq3 = Simplify[eq2, Assumptions -> {u > 0}]
```

> ```
> d == u (1 + Sqrt[pw^2/(r + a e1 r)^2] + Sqrt[pw^2/(w + a e1 w)^2])
> ```

Solving is now trivial.

```
soln = Solve[eq3, u][[1]] // Simplify
```

> ```
> {u -> d/(1 + Sqrt[pw^2/(r + a e1 r)^2] + Sqrt[pw^2/(w + a e1 w)^2])}
> ```

Finally, to get `w1` it is only necessary to evaluate `u^2`.

```
w1 = u^2 /. soln; w1
```

> ```
> d^2/(1 + Sqrt[pw^2/(r + a e1 r)^2] + Sqrt[pw^2/(w + a e1 w)^2])^2
> ```

Comment: Thank you, was not aware of the Join[] function.